# GitHub not seeing commits

Tags: git, github

I am very new to GitHub and cant understand why I cannot see the changes reflected in the online repository.

I am using Git Bash and running 
   `git add .` 
in the root folder of my project.

I then run `git commit -m "Change 1"`  and when I go on the GitHub site to see my repository the changes are not being reflected

I am probably just being really stupid but I have no idea what the problem is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you actually pushing your changes to GitHub? you need to do:

```
git push
```

or, if you want to push the current branch to a specific branch

```
git push origin <remote branch name>
```

But if you've set up your tracking branches correctly, the first version should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You commit your changes in local, you should push it to remote origin.

try `git push origin master`